# $digest rendering ng-repeat as a comment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a test for a directive, when executing the test the template (which is loaded correctly) is rendered just as `<!-- ng-repeat="foo in bar" -->`

For starters the relevant parts of the code:

**Test**

```
...

beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache) {

    var scope = $rootScope;
    scope.prop = [ 'element0', 'element1', 'element2' ];

    // Template loading, in the real code this is done with html2js, in this example
    // I'm gonna load just a string (already checked the problem persists)
    var template = '<strong ng-repeat="foo in bar"> <p> {{ foo }} </p> </strong>';
    $templateCache.put('/path/to/template', [200, template, {}]);

    el = angular.element('<directive-name bar="prop"> </directive-name>');
    $compile(el)(scope);
    scope.$digest(); // <--- here is the problem
    isolateScope = el.isolateScope();

    // Here I obtain just the ng-repeat text as a comment
    console.log(el); // <--- ng-repeat="foo in bar" --> 
}));

...
```

---

**Directive**

The directive is fairly simple and it's not the problem (outside the test everything works just fine):

```
app.directive('directiveName', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
    replace : true,
    scope : {
        bar : '='
    },
    templateUrl : '/path/to/template', // Not used in this question, but still...
});
```

A few more details:

- The directive, outside the test, works fine
- If I change the template to something far more simple like: `<h3> {{ bar[0] }} </h3>` the test works just fine
- The rootScope is loaded correctly
- The isolateScope results as `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the generated output that angular creates for `ng-repeat` you will find comments in your html. For example:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: foo in bars  -->
```

These comments are created by the compile function - see the angular sources:

```
document.createComment(' ' + directiveName + ': '+templateAttrs[directiveName]+' ')
```

What you get if you call `console.log(el);` is that created comment. You may check this if you change the output in this way: console.log(el[0].parentNode). You will see that there are a lot of childNodes:
[image]

If you use the directive outside of a test you will not be aware of this problem, because your element `directive-name` will be replaced by the complete created `DocumentFragment`. Another way to solve the problem is using a wrapping element for your directive template:

```
<div><strong ng-repeat="foo in bar"> <p> {{ foo }} </p> </strong></div>
```

In this case you have access to the `div` element.